# information_schema shows "unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE" mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have phpmyadmin installed on linux web server.

WHen i log into phpmyadmin using root user to see information_schema and click on table called triggers then at the bottom of table structure i see this line

```
unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE
```

Is that the error or something else

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be an [error in phpmyadmin](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2959746&group_id=23067&atid=377408)

I updated to version 3.4.0 and the message is gone.