# Creating multiple SQL Data from For-loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to add random `x` and `y` values to a MySQL database but strangely it only seems to ever add one value. I was looking at many of the other posts of similar issues on Stackoverflow and it just seemed they did not have query within the loop was the common issue. I do have the query in the loop and am unsure why it is still not working.

Please see my code below:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "myTable";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++){
    $x = rand(0,20);
    $y = rand(0,200);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (x, y)"
    $sql .= "VALUES ($x, $y);";
    //mysql_query($sql);

    if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New records created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: If it's MySQL, then please don't tag SQL Server; they are not the same product (or even owned by the same company). Every DBMS is different, so it's important to know which one you are using. I've removed the tag for you.

Comment: are their any key constraints on `x` and `y` in your table ? If anyone of them is PK or Unique key, then your query may fail, because same random value may appear

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya I do not believe I did but I do not need to have any constraints on those values is there a certain way I should set up these two variables. Thank you

Comment: you are using mysql multiquery but you should use mysqli_query since you are running a single query each time you do a new step of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your for loop to look something like this, and it worked perfectly fine for me.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++){
    $x = rand(0,20);
    $y = rand(0,200);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (x, y) VALUES ('$x', '$y')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($result)
    {
        echo "Successfully created record " . $i;
    } else
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    ob_start();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    usleep(001000);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

it Delay's the loop by just a little like a fifth of a second in total. The reason I have delayed the iteration is because your database might have a limit on how many queries can be sent within a time frame. It works for me let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That makes sense to me so when I ran the code and tried to check the data it gives an error " Unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE" right now I make they type as Collation

Comment: where does your db exists is it online at phpmyadmin or somewhere else? you might also try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955097/information-schema-shows-unknown-table-status-table-type-mysql-phpmyadmin) it just has that you might need to update your server version.

Comment: I am using UWAMP it is a phpmyadmin and is only hosted locally

Comment: ok let me see if I can find anything specific to UWAMP and "Unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE".

Comment: As far as I can find it has to do with either your db version, UWAMP version or The redestributable that you are using I would recommend going to uwamp's site and downloading the latest redestributable, and if that doesn't fix the problem try the latest UWAMP exe file, and install that and if that doesn't work then your DB's version needs to be changed you can look into that. Hope this helps. Just try those options.

Comment: So the error is gone now but the logical error still occurs only 1 data point is added

Answer (score 0):

Create the values array in the for loop, then use implode to build the query outside the loop.

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "myTable";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_errno) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (x, y) VALUES ";
    $values = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++){
        $x = rand(0,20);
        $y = rand(0,200);
        $values[] = "($x, $y)";
    }

    $query = $sql . implode(",", $values) . ";";
    $r = $conn->query($query);

    if ($r) {
      echo "New records created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $query  . "<br>" . $conn->connect_error;
    }

    $conn->close();
```

Comment: I see your point but strangely even with this code the result is the same and only 1 data set is added to the table

Comment: Well that makes no sense, if you print $query you will see something like:
`INSERT INTO data (x, y) VALUES (2, 136),(16, 144),(19, 139),(17, 36),(19, 165),(16, 31);` (but longer), If you execute this query it will insert all the rows at once. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

You are just running a single query for each loop. No need for multi query

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++){
    $x = rand(0,20);
    $y = rand(0,200);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (x, y)"
    $sql .= "VALUES ($x, $y);";
    //mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
        echo "New records created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's true about the single query I am still unsure as to why only one data point gets added instead of the iterated 100 values

Comment: Yes I have, the directory of my database is like so. Database is called "mytable" and the table is called "data" both x and y are type "int(11)"

Comment: and you do not get any error message from the output above?